# Subview has wrong orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom segue where I am trying to do the reverse of the standard "Cover Vertical" segue transition. I think this should work:

> ```
> UIView *srcView = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
> UIView *dstView = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;
>
> [dstView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, srcView.window.bounds.size.width, srcView.window.bounds.size.height)];
>
> [srcView.window insertSubview:dstView belowSubview:srcView];
>
> [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
>      animations:^{
>          srcView.center = CGPointMake(srcView.center.x - srcView.frame.size.width, srcView.center.y);
>      }
>      completion:^(BOOL finished){
>          [srcView removeFromSuperview];
>      }
>  ];
> ```

The problem is the destination view shows up in portrait orientation even though every other view in the app is landscape orientation. Also, the x and y coordinates are reversed. Why is this happening?

I have set up `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in every view controller, but that didn't help. I could rotate the view with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`, but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do; coordinates would still be reversed, for one thing.

**Update:**

I tried using `CGAffineTransformRotate` to rotate the view , but it looks ridiculous. Most of the background shows up black. I don't think this is the way it's suppose to work.

Comment: where are you calling this code from? `viewDidLoad` or is it called by a method you wrote?

Comment: From `- (void)perform`, which is part of a custom subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Comment: ok so is this `perform` being called initially, or after a button press or what triggers it? also, is everything else about the animation working (i.e. the animated view is visible and gets its frame set to the correct location)?

Comment: A button triggers it. I set the button up in a storyboard to call my custom class when clicked.

Comment: can you put an NSLog or a breakpoint into your destinationViewController's `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` to see if these get called before or after its frame gets set and the animation begins?

Comment: The `perform` function happens first, then `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it was much easier than I thought to do the segue I wanted. Here's is what worked:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    [src dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){ [src.view removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Since I was not able the get the correct orientation and framing of the destination view before the controllers exchange, I did reverse the process:

1. save the source view as an image (see [Remove custom UIStoryboardSegue with custom animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083184/remove-custom-uistoryboardsegue-with-custom-animation) ) ;
2. switch the current controller [presentViewController: ...];
3. then, do the animation with the (now correct) destination view embedding the saved source image.

Here is the complete code :

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation HorizontalSwipingSegue

- (void) perform {
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destination = self.destinationViewController;    
    UIView *sourceView = source.view;
    UIView *destinationView = destination.view;

    // Create a UIImageView with the contents of the source
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceView.bounds.size);
    [sourceView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageView *sourceImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sourceImage];

    [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:NULL];

    CGPoint destinationViewFinalCenter = CGPointMake(destinationView.center.x, destinationView.center.y);
    CGFloat deltaX = destinationView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat deltaY = destinationView.frame.size.height;

    switch (((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).interfaceOrientation) {
       case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            destinationView.center = CGPointMake(destinationView.center.x - deltaX, destinationView.center.y);                
            sourceImageView.center = CGPointMake(sourceImageView.center.x + deltaX, sourceImageView.center.y);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            destinationView.center = CGPointMake(destinationView.center.x + deltaX, destinationView.center.y);
            sourceImageView.center = CGPointMake(sourceImageView.center.x + deltaX, sourceImageView.center.y);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            destinationView.center = CGPointMake(destinationView.center.x, destinationView.center.y - deltaY);                
            sourceImageView.center = CGPointMake(sourceImageView.center.x + deltaY, sourceImageView.center.y);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            destinationView.center = CGPointMake(destinationView.center.x, destinationView.center.y + deltaY);
            sourceImageView.center = CGPointMake(sourceImageView.center.x + deltaY, sourceImageView.center.y);
            break;
    }

    [destinationView addSubview:sourceImageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                     animations:^{
                         destinationView.center = destinationViewFinalCenter; 
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sourceImageView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Make sure you are setting your dstView's frame correctly. I think you'll have better luck using:

```
dstView.frame = srcView.frame;
```

instead of:

```
[dstView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, srcView.window.bounds.size.width, srcView.window.bounds.size.height)];
```

the `bounds` property does not react to changes in orientation the same way `frame` does.

Comment: It didn't work. The frame is ok, but the orientation is wrong.

Comment: I don't know what the parent should be, though. I tried making the destination view controller a child of the source view controller and it says `child view controller:<...> should have parent view controller:(null)`. So it's telling me there should be no parent.

Comment: try asking the source view controller for its parent view controller with `self.sourceViewController.parentViewController` and then adding your destination view controller as a child to that. if the `sourceViewController` is a child of `self` in the code you provided, just add `destinationViewController` as a child of `self`

Comment: Like this: `[((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).parentViewController addChildViewController:self.destinationViewController];`? It didn't work either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14480/discussion-between-woz-and-pedro-cattori)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
[srcView insertSubview:dstView belowSubview:srcView];
```

with

```
[srcView insertSubview:dstView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding another view controller's view to your view hierarchy, that view controller is not going to get any information about the orientation of the device, so it will present the view in its default configuration. You need to add the view controller into the view controller hierarchy as well, using the containment methods described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController%3a). You also need to remove it from the hierarchy when done.

There are also several good WWDC talks on the subject, one from 2011 called "Implementing view controller containment" and one from this year, the evolution of view controllers.

Comment: Are you saying one view controller should be a child of the other? Isn't it enough that I'm adding the view to a window?